# How do I wrap title and the h1 headline toghether when windows is shrink

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to center both the title `<img class="title-image">` and h1 `<h1 class="big-heading">` together when the window is shrink to the minimum I've attached the two screenshots and the cover is underneath.

[image]

[image]

```css
title-image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
}

big-heading {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Black";
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  right: 700px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
  <img class="title-image" src="images/Stephan's Notes.Rs3.1-01.png" alt="logo-mockup">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
  <h1 class="big-heading">The place to book your radio, podcast and voice over appointments.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the page responsive
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thanks for VeryGoodCoder111. I've tried it but unfortunately it did not work.